# SQL Installation Error make sure file exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, dll, windows-8, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to Install SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition onto my Desktop I currently have Express Edition, I run the Install stages fine but as soon as I get to a certain part of the installation I receive this error:
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1 Setup

**Error reading from file D:\x86\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\PFiles\SqlServr\MSSQL.X\MSSQL\Binn\hadrres.dll.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.**

The file does exist within its location and I can't really see the problem here :( Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the express edition.  Run a tool like CC cleaner to remove old registry entries.  Install the developer version of the software.  You are installing the 32 bit version since it is referring to x86 directory.  Are you sure there is not disk/file issue going on with your system.  If you are still have the error after the uninstall, cleanup, and re-install, look there.

Comment: Hi any specific files for uninstallation on the express edition or the whole thing ? also which specific registers sorry for the questions a bit of a nooby on sql currently.